# Jquery form submit return false not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I'm including this form using ajax:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="number" name="user_id" placeholder="user id" id="user_id_input"/>
    <input type="submit" value="update">
</form>
```

My code:

```
$.get("application/views/beheer/html/"+widgetName+"div.html", function(response){
    $widgetDiv.html("<div class=\"widget_"+widgetName+"\" id=\""+widgetArray.length+"\">"+response+"</div>");
    var $form = $(".widget_"+widgetName).find("form");
    $form.submit(function( event ){
        UpdateObjectSettings($form);
        return false;
    });

});

function UpdateObjectSettings($form){
    //var id = $form.parent().attr("id");

    //widgetArray[(id - 1)].Update($form);
    return false;
}
```

If I enter an alert inside the $form.submit it still works.
If I decomment the lines inside the UpdateObjectSettings the return false inside the submit won't work.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: How are you triggering the `$.get()`?

Comment: Check the error console for errors - my guess is the second line in UpdateObjectSettings is throwing an error.

Comment: it looks like `UpdateObjectSettings` might be throwing an error

Comment: @evilunix Thanks you're right, error flashed by too fast for me to see.

Comment: @evilunix Could you post your comment as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the error console for errors - my guess is the second line in `UpdateObjectSettings` is throwing an error.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to add this. in my object function.